# Surpress year when citing an @online resource

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm using `biblatex` with the options `backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=anyt`.

When citing `@online` resources I want it to only display the `year` value and not the year listed in `urldate`. Meaning:

```
@online{resourceWithYear,
    label           = "Random Label",
    organization    = "Some organization",
    title           = "Lorem Ipsum",
    year            = "2018",
    month           = "April",
    url             = "https://localhost",
    urldate         = "2020-05-11",
}
```

This `\parencite{resourceWithYear}` translates to `(Random Label 2018)`.

However using this:

```
@online{resourceWithNoYear,
    label           = "Other Label",
    organization    = "Some other organization",
    title           = "Consectetur adipisici",
    url             = "https://localhost",
    urldate         = "2020-05-11",
}
```

`\parencite{resourceWithNoYear}` Should translate to `(Other Label)`.
Right now it displays as `(Other Label 2020)`, using the year value of the `urldate` tag.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but I would not use `sorting=anyt` with `style=authoryear,`. `anyvt` sorts primarily by the label that would be generated for the `alphabetic` style, which you don't use if you say `style=authoryear,`. If you don't set a `sorting` manually, `style=authoryear,` automatically selects `sorting=nyt,` which is much more sensible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer would be to remove `urldate` from the `\DeclareLabeldate` settings

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

this would give

> (Random Label 2018)
>
> (Other Label n.d.)

because `biblatex` produces "n.d." if no date can be found.

If you don't want `nodate` also remove `\literal{nodate}` from the definition.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{resourceWithYear,
  label           = {Random Label},
  organization    = {Some organization},
  title           = {Lorem Ipsum},
  year            = {2018},
  month           = apr,
  url             = {https://localhost},
  urldate         = {2020-05-11},
}
@online{resourceWithNoYear,
  label           = {Other Label},
  organization    = {Some other organization},
  title           = {Consectetur adipisici},
  url             = {https://localhost},
  urldate         = {2020-05-11},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{resourceWithYear,resourceWithNoYear}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Random Label 2018; Other Label)]

As commented under the question I have removed `sortingy=anyvt,` so the MWE just uses `sorting=nyt`.

I have also changed the incorrect `month = "April",` to `month = apr,` though I would have preferred `date = {2018-04},` instead of `year = {2018}, month = apr,`.